# HashMap does not give expected output

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, equals, hashcode

I have added some Dog objects in the below mentioned code.
I have implemented equals and hashcode methods.
Then while trying to get the value for Dog object I am getting this output

```
5
Third
```

On running this code, output is

```
5
null
```

Here's the code

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MapTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        HashMap<Dog, String> map = new HashMap<Dog, String>();

        Dog d1 = new Dog("Tiger");
        Dog d2 = new Dog("Tommy");
        Dog d3 = new Dog("Jackie");
        Dog d4 = new Dog("Sheru");
        Dog d5 = new Dog("Rahul");

        map.put(d1, "First");
        map.put(d2, "Second");
        map.put(d3, "Third");
        map.put(d4, "Fourth");
        map.put(d5, "Fifth");

       System.out.println(map.size());
       System.out.println(map.get(new Dog("Jackie")));
    }
}

class Dog {

    private String name;

    public Dog(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        System.out.println("inside equals");
        if ((obj instanceof Dog) && this.name.equals(((Dog) obj).name)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public int hashcode() {
        return this.name.hashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: Use the annotation @Override to avoid such kind of typo issue https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/predefined.html

Comment: Always always @Override

Answer (score 4):

The `hashcode()` method name is wrong, it should be `hashCode()`

Comment: If you annotate your overriden methods with `@Override`, the compiler would then help you notice this error.

Answer (score 0):

Your hashcode() method name was wrong and make it hashCode().

For details please find the code

```
class Dog {

    private String name;

    public Dog(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        System.out.println("inside equals");
        if ((obj instanceof Dog) && this.name.equals(((Dog) obj).name)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return this.name.hashCode();
    }
}
```